# Populate Dynamic Fields Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, dynamic-programming, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to create a dynamic function that gets an array of fields, filter object, and a schema model, and populates the fields in the array.

for example:
instead of populating like this-

```
getCardByName=(Model,filter)=>{ 
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             Model.findOne(filter).populate({ path: "user" })
                 .populate({ path: "socialMedia" })
                 .populate({ path: 'galleryList' })
                 .populate({ path: 'reviewsList' })
                 .populate({ path: 'lead' })
                 .populate({ path: 'statistic', })
                 .exec(async(err, card) => {
                     if (err) {
                         reject(err);
                     }
                     resolve(card)
                 })
       });
}
```

I want to create a dynamic function something like this:

```
 //assume arr is a function argument
    arr=["user", "socialMedia", "galleryList", "reviewsList", "lead", "statistic"]
    let populateStr=""
        arr.forEach(path => {
            populateStr+=`.populate({path: ${path}})`
        });
        console.log(populateStr)
        return new Promise(async(resolve, reject)=>{
            try{
              await Model.findOne(filter).populateStr
              .exec(async(err,card)=>{
                  if(err)
                  {
                      reject(err)
                      resolve(card)
                  }
              })

              }
        catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    }
    })
```

when I run this code, I get the population string but the population itself doesn't really happen.

(TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined)

Do you have any idea of doing it or fixing the code I wrote?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var query = Model.findOne(filter);

arr.forEach(path => {
    query.populate(path);
});

query.exec(async (err, card) => {
    if (err)
        reject(err)
    else 
        resolve(card)
});
```

There's no reason to use await for `Model.findOne` when you use resolve/reject in the exec calback function. Also no need for try/catch.

Comment: it worked, thank you. now, if I want to add a filter? for example- match?

Comment: Unless i'm mistaken, the $match is only available in `aggregate` function. So you need to be more specific.

Comment: something like this:       
    Model.findOne(filter)
            .populate({
                path: "cards",
                populate: [
                    { path: 'user' },
                    { path: 'socialMedia' },
                    { path: 'galleryList' },
                    { path: 'reviewsList' },
                    { path: 'lead' },
                    { path: 'statistic' }
                ],
                match: { isDelete: false }
            })